# want to route emails to VPS except one at gsuit

Tags: ubuntu, email-server, g-suite

I have VPS that host website and its emails. One of the email of my website domain is connected to GSuit.

How to configure MX so relevant emails route to related server.

Domain, `example.com`

**MX:**

1. `ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.`
2. `mail.example.com`

Only single email need to route 1st mx record. All other emails of example.com should be route through 2nd.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, but if you mean that one particular email address should go to the first MX record, and all other emails should go to the second, then this is something you can't do with MX records - instead you would need to set up forwarding.

Comment: @Jenny yes you exactly understand it

Comment: so let me know how I can setup forwarding at Gsuit or at my VPS. Any one I think should be implemented

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with MX records. All emails will need to be directed to a single MX (or set of MXes) and then routed from there to their final destination.

Comment: so how to redirect emails from Gsuit

Comment: Email routing rules. For more details, you can contact GSuite support.

Comment: But this will route all emails, I need one of the email to be with gsuit

Comment: You either need to send all emails to your server or all emails to Google, then from one of those mail systems, route emails not destined there to there final server.

Comment: any link to follow procedure

Answer (score 1):

A few years ago, the company I was working with at the time was considering using GSuite (called Google Apps for Work at that time). Initially the needs would be the exact same as in your scenario.

I called Google support to ask about the possibility of achieving this, and the solution they offered me was the following:

- Keep our `MX` record for `example.com` pointing to `mail.example.com`.
- For the user `fl@example.com` to be hosted on GSuite forward all emails from our mail server to `fl@example.com.test-google-a.com`.

I don't know if that exact configuration is still the recommended way to do it. But at least one thing hasn't changed:

The MX records for a domain cannot direct emails in different directions based on local-part, so emails have to be delivered to one location which can forward a subset of emails send to the domain to another server.

The variations between different ways of solving the problem is which of the servers will initially receive the email, and how will it forward some of them to a different server.

Comment: Is there any way to forward specific emails to example.com from Gsuit.

Comment: @VeeZPhone You can log in to the account in Gsuite and in settings you can either set up forwarding for all incoming email to the address or use filters to forward only selected emails to the address. I do not know if Gsuite offers any way to forward all email delivered to the domain, even if the destination address does not exist in Gusite.

Comment: @VeeZPhone This link may be relevant to you as well: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2685650